# Target iphone XR in Zoomed mode and not iphone6 with media queries

Tags: css, ios, media-queries

I know it's possible to target specific iphone models with media queries like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

However the iphone XR in zoomed mode has exactly the same pixel size/ratio as the 6,7,8 models, does anyone know of a way to target just the iphone XR in zoomed mode?

Answer (score 0):

We can recognize device with its screen height and width, I did this for getting heights

```
  extension UIScreen {
    var isPhone4: Bool {
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 960;
    }
    var isPhone5: Bool {
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 1136;
    }
    var isPhone6: Bool {
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 1334;
    }
    var isPhone6Plus: Bool {
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 2208;
    }
    var isPhoneX: Bool {
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 2436;
    }
    var isPhoneXsMax: Bool{
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 2688;
    }
    var isPhoneXR:Bool{
        return self.nativeBounds.size.height == 1792;
    }

}
```